# Pandas where clause after a count

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas DataFrame called df:

```
   col_A id name
0      4  1   n1
1     39  2   n1
2     49  3   n2
3      1  4   n2
4      0  5   n2
```

Suppose a do a ***count*** on column *id* after having grouped by column *name*:

```
df.groupby('name')['id'].count()
```

so that I get the different counts of *id* per *name*. I get

```
name
n1    2
n2    3
```

How would I then sort this frame I obtained by the count (which is not a column, apparently)? I'd like to either sort if by descending/ascending counts and, potentially, retrieve only the counts which meet a certain **where** clause (say those > 2).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The type returned is a `Series` you can call `sort` or [`sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.sort_values.html#pandas.Series.sort_values) (if running a 0.17.0 or later version of pandas) on this with param `ascending=True`:

```
In [51]:
counts = df.groupby(['name'])['id'].count()
counts.sort_values(ascending=True)
counts

Out[51]:
name
n1    2
n2    3
Name: id, dtype: int64
```

You can filter the series by passing a boolean condition to generate a mask:

```
In [52]:
counts[counts > 2]

Out[52]:
name
n2    3
Name: id, dtype: int64
```

The mask looks like this:

```
In [53]:
counts > 2

Out[53]:
name
n1    False
n2     True
Name: id, dtype: bool
```